# How to programmatically remove "singleton information" on an instance to make it marshal?

Tags: ruby, singleton, metaprogramming, marshalling

I have created an object that failed to marshal due to a "singleton metaclass definition executed on runtime" (Is this description of what the code does correct?).

This is performed by following code:

```
# define class X that my use singleton class metaprogramming features
# through call of method :break_marshalling!
class X
   def break_marshalling!
     meta_class = class << self
       self 
     end
     meta_class.send(:define_method, :method_y) do 
      return 
    end
  end
end

# prepare my instance of X now
instance_of_x = X.new

# marshalling fine here
Marshal.dump instance_of_x

# break marshalling with metprogramming features
instance_of_x.break_marshalling!

Marshal.dump instance_of_x
# fails with TypeError: singleton can't be dumped
```

What can I do to make the object marshall correct? Is it possible to "remove" the singleton components from `class X` of object `instance_of_x`?

I really need an advise on that because of some of our objects needed to be cached through Marshal.dump serialization mechanism. This code is executed in ruby-1.9.3 but I expect it to behave similar in ruby-2.0 or ruby-2.1

Comment: Good question, but you've triggered one of my biggest peeves! It's called the [`singleton_class`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Object.html#method-i-singleton_class). And we don't need that send hack with [`define_singleton_method`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Object.html#method-i-define_singleton_method) around either.

Comment: So @Max have you come across any way of programmatically "reset" the singleton_class of an instance of any ruby class? Something like `remove_singleton_class_information!` perhaps? ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [define custom `marshal_dump` and `marshal_load` methods](http://docs.rubydocs.org/ruby-1-9-3-p547/classes/Marshal.html):

```
class X
  def break_marshalling!
    meta_class = class << self
      self 
    end
    meta_class.send(:define_method, :method_y) do 
      return 
    end
  end

  # This should return an array of instance variables
  # needed to correctly restore any X instance. Assuming none is needed
  def marshal_dump
    []
  end

  # This should define instance variables
  # needed to correctly restore any X instance. Assuming none is needed
  def marshal_load(_)
    []
  end
end

# Works fine
restored_instance_of_x = 
  Marshal.load Marshal.dump(X.new.tap { |x| x.break_marshalling! })

# Does not work
restored_instance_of_x.method_y
```

---

If you want you can manage dynamic methods definitions via `method_missing`:

```
class X
  def method_missing(name, *args)
    if name == :method_y
      break_marshalling!
      public_send name, *args
    else
      super
    end
  end
end

# Works fine
Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(X.new)).method_y
```

Comment: Do you mean `meta_class = class << self ...`? I guess (and hope) the asker to have some good reason to use it =)

Comment: Somehow I noticed it in your answer before I saw it in the question. Oops.

Comment: First thanks for this answer. The asker didn't actually use this method of adding singleton methods on his code, but tried to marshal objects created by a library used in his projects ^^. Btw. he is also very interested in understanding [singleton_class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Object.html#method-i-singleton_class) behavior inside ruby, too.

Comment: Criss why are you referring to the asker in third person??? Aren't you the asker??? I'm confused!!! :D

Comment: actually I am. So you really can stop being confused.

Comment: To perhaps complete the answer a little more: marshal_dump can do anything it wants but what ever it returns is what will be passed to marshal_load as the argument.  marshal_load then needs to figure out how to recreate the original object (thus, marshal_dump needs to somehow supply it will everything that is needed).  In my case, my parent class was Hash.  So I used JSON.generate(self) as marshal_dump and then recreated a temp hash using JSON.parser(arg) and used the keys in the temp has to recreate the object.

Answer (score 6):

The one-liner way to (usually) remove singleton information from `instance_of_x`:

```
instance_of_x = instance_of_x.dup
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is such a thing is `remove_singleton_class_information!`, but you can try to programatically undefine things in the singleton class.

According to [the documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Marshal.html#method-c-dump) Marshal doesn't like objects with singleton methods. With some experimentation, it seems it also doesn't like objects with a singleton class that has instance variables.

```
class Foo
  def break_marshal
    singleton_class.class_eval do
      @@x = true
      @x = false
      define_method :bar do
        puts @@x
        puts singleton_class.instance_variable_get(:@x)
        puts singleton_class.send(:baz)
        puts singleton_class.const_get(:X)
      end
      define_singleton_method :baz do
        "Singleton method in a singleton"
      end
    end
  end

  def fix_marshal
    singleton_methods.each { |m| singleton_class.send(:remove_method, m) }
    singleton_class.class_eval do
      instance_variables.each { |v| remove_instance_variable v }
    end
  end
end

f = Foo.new
f.break_marshal
f.singleton_class.const_set(:X, 1)
f.bar
f.fix_marshal

Marshal.dump f
```

Note how hard I tried to break Marshal. I gave the singleton a class variable, an instance variable, a method, its own singleton method, and a constant. But Marshal works fine if you just remove the singleton method and the instance variable.

**However**, I don't think this is the right way to marshal such an object. @mdesantis's answer of defining your own `marshal_dump` and `marshal_load` is more proper.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this method, which recursively removes singleton_methods from an object, and from objects assigned to instance variables:

```
def self.strip_singleton(obj)
  obj = obj.dup unless (obj.nil? || obj.singleton_methods.empty?)
  obj.instance_variables.each do |var|
    obj.instance_variable_set(var, strip_singleton(obj.instance_variable_get(var)))
  end
  obj
end
```