# Inspecting Marshal methods

Tags: ruby

Marshal.dump is unable to dump classes that include a singleton(eigenclass).  I'd like to see how the method determines the presence of this singleton but I do not know how to go about finding the source.  I did try the following:

```
dump_method = Marshal.method(:dump) #=> #<Method: Marshal.dump> 
dump_method.source_location # => nil
```

I also took a quick look at https://github.com/ruby/ruby but, without a search capability, I have no idea where to find the source for Marshal.

Comment: Relevant: [How to programmatically remove “singleton information” on an instance to make it marshal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23734582/how-to-programmatically-remove-singleton-information-on-an-instance-to-make-it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The check is [here](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/marshal.c#L497), but it is in C - and MRI code is infamously opaque.

I believe a check similar to that, but in Ruby, would be:

```
obj.singleton_class.instance_methods(false).empty? &&
obj.singleton_class.instance_variables.empty?
```

If that is `false` (i.e. if anything is defined on the singleton), no dump for you.

Comment: For some extended object, I used `.singleton_methods` and `.instance_variables`.